# Umbraco Examine - querying issue

Tags: c#, lucene, umbraco, umbraco7, examine

I have the following data value for the object I am retrieving with Examine ([image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sUOb.jpg) for easier viewing):

```
__Icon: icon-shopping-basket-alt-2 color-red __IndexType: content __NodeId: 1413 __NodeTypeAlias: sale __Path: -1,1098,1410,1413 id: 1413 nodeName: Sale test 1 (active) nodeTypeAlias: Sale path: 1098 1410 1413 saleEndDate: 20151231160336000 saleStartDate: 20151026160321000 updateDate: 2015-11-18T17:03:05 writerName: Admin
```

The **path** attribute is stripped version of **__Path**. This was done because there were issues with starting the query with *-1* and having commas as query values.

The problem I am experiencing is related with having to query a part of **path**, for example - retrieving the objects that *contain* the desired id (in a particular case just *1410*).

I have executed the following query in *Examine Manager* from *Umbraco*: `+nodeTypeAlias: sale +path:1468`.

The C# code example looks like this:

```
var queryAllSalesInDepartment = searchCriteria
                                        .Field(Constant.Examine.AttributeFields.NodeTypeAlias, Constant.DocumentTypeAlias.Sale)
                                        .And().Field(Constant.Examine.AttributeFields.Path, Umbraco.AssignedContentItem.Parent.Id.ToString())
                                        .Compile();
```

The query yields 0 results, despite the fact that there are available values in indexes.

Am I doing the query wrong or should I reconsider formatting the path value differently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, the query needs to be "fuzzier" :-s You can go the (in my opinion) hard-to-read way like this: https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/extending-umbraco/11659-Examine-quering-path or the raw query way like this:

```
searchCriteria.RawQuery(@"+path:\-1*" + parentId + "*");
```

parentId being 1410 in your example.

Comment: *RawQuery* works like a charm, thank you! I will  investigate the implementation from [our.umbraco link](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/extending-umbraco/11659-Examine-quering-path) and let you know if this works. Also, I had to get back the *-1* id in the *Path* since the * cannot be 'escaped' - from the main reason that field querying doesn't allow * as the first character.

Comment: I wish I would be able to upvote 10 times this answer!! Thanks :) Now, I can go sleep.