# Lucene wildcard for substring query

Tags: c#, lucene, wildcard, umbraco, examine

I want to get all members where field "username" contains substring e.g - "user" with the help of Lucene Wildcards.

Member's Username is "username"

"user" - not found

"rname" - not found

"usernam" - found

I used code below, but it seems that it works not in all cases;

```
                string alias = "username";
                IBooleanOperation op;
                IQuery query;
                var values = Value.Split(',');
                if (values.Length > 0)
                {
                    string searchQuery = $"({alias}:({string.Join("~ ", values)}~))";
                    op = query.And(op).NativeQuery(searchQuery);
                }
```

I need something like in SQL: WHERE [username] LIKE '%user%'

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure the alias of your member username is actually "username"? The alias for the built in member username (called "Login" in the backoffice) is "_umb_login", while that becomes "loginName" in the MembersIndex. Which is another point - remember to look in the MembersIndex and not ExternalIndex when looking for members.
2. In Examine wildcard is * and not ~ (as far as I understand). For fuzzy searches I'd even recommend giving RawQuery a try, like here: [Umbraco Examine - querying issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33798937/umbraco-examine-querying-issue/33801324#33801324)
3. Also take a look at the example here, if you haven't already: https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Reference/Searching/Examine/quick-start/#getting-the-content - it looks like you might have misunderstood something with the boolean operator?